# PHP - Adding lunar month to date in PHP, carolan window

Tags: php, date, fibonacci

I tried to calculate date in php based on this formula:

```
<?PHP
$lunarMonth = 29.530589;
function getFib($n)
{
    return round(pow((sqrt(5)+1)/2, $n) / sqrt(5));
}
$fibbonaciNumber = getFib(2);
$addToDate = sqrt($fibbonaciNumber*$lunarMonth);
$date = '2017-01-01';
$timeStamp = strtotime($date);
$calucatedDate = $timeStamp+$addToDate;
echo 'Date: '.date('Y-m-d', $calucatedDate).'<br>';
?>
```

But it dosen't work, i cant calculate new date by using timeStamp function. What should i try?

Sample output is:
addToDate: 24.902657870195
timeStemp: 1483311600
CalculateDate: 1483311624.9027
Date: 2017-01-02

This show always the same date, no matter what CalculateDate date is.

I current using excel to calculate this:

```
=DATE(YEAR(A4)+0#MONTH(A4)+0#DAY(A4)+(29,530589*(SQRT(1)))),
```

for example input: 2009-02-18, should output: 2009-03-18, for fibonacci number 1

I need to move base date based on calucation $fibbonaciNumber*$lunarMonth

Thanks

Comment: And what "it dosen't work" actually mean? _Be precise in your questions if you want answers..._

Comment: Sample output addToDate: 24.902657870195,
timeStemp: 1483311600,
calculateDate: 1483311624.9027,
Date: 2017-01-02

Comment: Please add additional information to the question itself, there is an `edit` link for that. Thanks.

Comment: I mean it doesnt calcuate date, it always giving the same date.

Comment: arkascha, sorry for the problems. i edited post. thanks :)

Comment: Well, the conversions look fine so far, though a bit fuzzy because of the procedural style. But that's ok. The issue is probably that the value you compute in `$addToDate` is so tiny (`float(5.4342054617028)`) against the dates timestamp (`int(1483225200)`) that the result always lies inside the same date.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah. That's my problem, how can i calculate it in correct way?

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell you. I have no idea about what you do. To the the connection between astronomy (lunar month) and the algebra (Fibonacci numbers) is not at all obvious.

Comment: Maybe excel formula can help you understand: =DATE(YEAR(A4)+0#MONTH(A4)+0#DAY(A4)+(29,530589*(SQRT(1)))), for example input: 2009-02-18, should output: 2009-03-18, for fibonacci number 1

Comment: One question: what does the Fibonacci series have to do with this? A lunar month is something close to 30 days. Why can't you simply add that?

Comment: You specify the manth duration as 29.xxx _days_, but the timestamp per definition is computed in _seconds_. So you'd have to multiply that by 24*60*60 or am I wrong. Still the number is too small, no idea why, but as said I do not get the logic behind that calculation. However if you additionally multiply the value to be added by say factor 100, then you _do_ get another date as a result. Which supports the initial remark that your addition is _far_ too small to change the computed date.

Comment: It need to be very accurate. I need to calcuate this with fibonacci, because i need to calculate more than 1 date, with another number from fionacci sqrt(lunarMonth * [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8...])

Comment: Why a square root? Sorry, not trying to be picky. But if you ask how to "fix" something without telling us what _exactly_ it is you are trying to implement, then we hardly can help.

Comment: Just checked: if I compute the same _without_ taking the square root, then I get `2017-01-30`...

Comment: It's used to calculate stock market timing prediction based on the spiral calendar and elliot waves theory. OK, my questions simpilfied: how to do math operations on date, including added days from math formula?

Comment: So does this answer your question? Introduction of the day-to-sec-factor and the removal of the square root?